# ImportError: cannot import name ellipkm1 (import seaborn issue)

Tags: python, importerror, seaborn

I am trying to run the below code in Jupyter Notebook but hitting the error give below. **ERROR pasted below**, can someone help me with a resolution?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

values = np.array([1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 6, 4])
example_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'value': values,
    'even': values % 2 == 0,
    'above_three': values > 3 
}, index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])

# Change False to True for this block of code to see what it does

# groupby() without as_index
if True:
    first_even = example_df.groupby('even').first()
    print first_even
    print first_even['even'] # Causes an error. 'even' is no longer a column in the DataFrame
```

**ERROR**:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-414-7b44697e4465> in <module>()
      2 import numpy as np
      3 import pandas as pd
----> 4 import seaborn as sns
      5 
      6 values = np.array([1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 6, 4])

C:\Users\...\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\seaborn\__init__.py in <module>()
      4 
      5 # Import seaborn objects
----> 6 from .rcmod import *
      7 from .utils import *
      8 from .palettes import *

C:\Users\...\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\seaborn\rcmod.py in <module>()
      6 import matplotlib as mpl
      7 
----> 8 from . import palettes, _orig_rc_params
      9 
     10 

C:\Users\...\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\seaborn\palettes.py in <module>()
     10 from .external.six.moves import range
     11 
---> 12 from .utils import desaturate, set_hls_values, get_color_cycle
     13 from .xkcd_rgb import xkcd_rgb
     14 from .crayons import crayons

C:\Users\...\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\seaborn\utils.py in <module>()
      6 
      7 import numpy as np
----> 8 from scipy import stats
      9 import pandas as pd
     10 import matplotlib as mpl

C:\Users\...\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py in <module>()
    342 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
    343 
--> 344 from .stats import *
    345 from .distributions import *
    346 from .morestats import *

C:\Users\...\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py in <module>()
    171 from scipy._lib._version import NumpyVersion
    172 from numpy import array, asarray, ma, zeros
--> 173 import scipy.special as special
    174 import scipy.linalg as linalg
    175 import numpy as np

C:\Users\...\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py in <module>()
    636 from ._ufuncs import *
    637 
--> 638 from .basic import *
    639 from . import specfun
    640 from . import orthogonal

C:\Users\...\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\basic.py in <module>()
     13                    where, mgrid, sin, place, issubdtype, extract,
     14                    less, inexact, nan, zeros, atleast_1d, sinc)
---> 15 from ._ufuncs import (ellipkm1, mathieu_a, mathieu_b, iv, jv, gamma,
     16                       psi, _zeta, hankel1, hankel2, yv, kv, _gammaln,
     17                       ndtri, errprint, poch, binom, hyp0f1)

ImportError: cannot import name ellipkm1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when importing seaborn, I simply checked if it was installed on my Python distribution and it wasn't. In my case I have Anaconda, for the installation I used:

```
conda install seaborn
```

You will also have to import spicy package before importing seaborn:

```
import scipy as sp
```